# Mongodb - use of $ , updating a value in a sub-array

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a collection (`favorites`) with documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 907,
    "pictures" : [
        {
        "id" : 107,
        "url" : "http://url1",
        "title" : "some title"
        },
        {
        "id" : 111,
        "url" : "http://url2",
        "title" : "some other title"
        }
    ]
}
```

It's fairly easy to get just the urls using `pictures.url`.

But how do I update the url for all users that saved the picture with an `id=111` as their favorite?

I found an work-around using:

```
107:['id':107,'url':'http://url1','title':'some title']
```

...and then using `find()` with `pictures.107.id => 107`, but that looks silly to me.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Which URL do you want to update? The one for `107` or `111`? Or both?

Comment: doesn't matter , really, I am just looking to see if there's a better way of doing multiple updates, without relying on the workaround I mentioned (basically storing the picture_id twice), and hopefully still preserving the `pictures.url` in `find()`. with the workaround I am forced to get from mongo all fields in `pictures`

Comment: I posted an answer but given the other replies I may not have understood your original question (which, frankly, is a little unclear). What exactly is it you need to do? Just update all "url" values for all users that have 111 as their favorite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're looking for, but I'll give it a shot.

In MongoDB, you can do [atomic updates](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations) with the `$set` operator, which will replace only the data you pass and not the whole document.

If you use it with the [`$elemMatch`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch) operator when selecting, you can update only the `url` of the `pictures` that match your query:

```
$mongo->selectCollection('mydb', 'favorites')
      ->update(
           array('pictures' => array(
               '$elemMatch' => array('id' => 107),
           )),
           array('$set' => array('pictures.$.url' => 'http://foobar'))
        );
```

You can see that the update contains `pictures.$.url`, where the `$` refers to the element(s) that matched the `$elemMatch` query.

The above will update all the `pictures.url` in your `favorites` that match `111` as their `pictures.id`, giving you something like:

```
{ "_id" : 907, "pictures" : [
    {
        "id" : 107,
        "url" : "http://url1",
        "title" : "some title"
    },
    {
        "id" : 111,
        "title" : "some other title",
        "url" : "http://foobar" // only this one has matched
    }
] }
```

Comment: thanks, as it turns out, the solution was very simple - (`$elemMatch`)

Answer (score 1):

```
db.favorites.update({pictures: {$elemMatch:{id:111}}}, {'pictures.$.title':"Some Title"}, false, true)
```